# Verify result set has a row for each value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to check that if a record exists for a given SubId/WorkflowId combination with `ProcessCode = 10` that the same `SubId/WorkflowId` combination has a row with a `ProcessCode` 20, 30, and 40.  Below is a poorly written version of what I'm trying to do; I'm hoping for a more elegant solution. This query is basically identifying anything that is breaking the rule.

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM @DataTable WHERE SubID = @SubId and WorkflowId = @WorkflowId and ProcessCode = 10)
AND (
NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM @DataTable WHERE SubID = @SubId and WorkflowId = @WorkflowId  and ProcessCode = 20) or 
NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM @DataTable WHERE SubId = @SubId and WorkflowId = @WorkflowId and ProcessCode = 30) or
NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM @DataTable WHERE SubID = @SubId and WorkflowId = @WorkflowId and ProcessCode = 40)
)
```

Comment: Is there always going to be 4 records? You could just check that, if there exists a record with ProcessCode 10, that `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE SubId = @SubId AND WorkflowId = @WorkflowId AND ProcessCode IN (10, 20, 30, 40) = 4`

Comment: you can also do `NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM @DataTable 
            WHERE SubID = @SubId and WorkflowId = @WorkflowId  
            and ProcessCode IN (20,30,40))`

Comment: @dash I thought of that, but possibly it gets an extra reading, value 20 happens twice and we get no value 30.  The count will still come out as four so the test passes, but it's really failing.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT ProcessCode)` could work

Comment: I don't get it, the listing you posted contains NOT EXISTS clauses, which says that you are looking for  `SubId` and `WorkflowId` that has 10 and do do not have at least one of 20, 30 and 40. Am I correct, or I missed something?

Comment: @msmucker0527, makes sense... `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @DataTable WHERE SubId = @SubId AND WorkflowId = @WorkflowId AND ProcessCode = 10)
  AND (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ProcessCode)) FROM @DataTable WHERE SubId = @SubId AND WorkflowId = @WorkflowId AND ProcessCode IN (20,30,40)) <> 3` should give me the results I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to find all of the SubID's and WorkFlowID's that have ProcessCode 10, but do not have a 20/30/40 you could use this query as opposed to checking each Sub/Workflow individually.

```
SELECT 
    SubID,
    WorkFlowID
FROM @DataTable 
GROUP BY SubID, WorkFlowID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN ProcessCode = '10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
AND COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN ProcessCode IN ('20','30','40') THEN ProcessCode ELSE NULL END)) < 3
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64f6d/1)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM @DataTable DT
    LEFT JOIN @DataTable DT2 ON DT.SubId = DT2.SubId AND DT.WorkflowId = DT2.WorkflodId AND DT2.ProcessCode IN (20, 30, 40)
    WHERE DT.ProcessCode = 10 AND DT2.ProcessCode IS NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM @DataTable WHERE SubID = @SubId and WorkflowId = @WorkflowId and ProcessCode = 10)
AND (NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM @DataTable WHERE SubID = @SubId and WorkflowId = @WorkflowId  and ProcessCode in (20, 30, 40)))
```